# How can I plot bars that are stacked on top of one another in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a bar chart from this dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)
mydf=data.frame(c("A","B","C","D"),c(100,110,90,120),c(150,200,160,180))
names(mydf)=c("myfirstC","mysecondC","mythirdC")
```

In order to plot a bar chart with bars that are stacked on top of one another, I am trying to use this code:

```
ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x=myfirstC))+
    geom_col(aes(y=mysecondC), colour="blue")+
    geom_col(aes(y=mythirdC), colour="red")
head(mydf)
```

Unfortunately, this code only returns a plot with bars from the "mythirdC"-column only.

Question: How do I need to change the code in order to get a stacked plot, *without* reshaping the dataframe?

Comment: It should be `gather(mydf, var, val, mysecondC:mythirdC) %>% ggplot(., aes(x = myfirstC, y = val, fill = var)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: I believe that your suggestion is the way you should actually do it. But I don't quite understand yet: Why is this the way that it should be?

Comment: It could be due to consistency and if there are many columns, then it becomes easier with the reshaped approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your really don't want to reshape you can try this:

```
ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x=myfirstC))+
   geom_col(aes(y=mysecondC+mythirdC), fill="blue")+
   geom_col(aes(y=mythirdC), fill="red")
```

[image]